# Publishing a Razor Page Template fails with "config changed by another program"

Tags: 2013-sp1, configuration, razormediator

I have Razor Mediator 4 Tridion 1.3.3.1 installed on Tridion 2013 SP1 with a single publisher.

When I attempt to publish a page template, it fails in the publishing queue. The error message shown is,

`The configuration file has been changed by another program. (C:\apps\sdl\cm\config\Tridion.ContentManager.config)`

I definitely don't have the config file open in any editors. I did edit it, after installation, to modify `adminUser` attribute in the `<razor.mediator >` node. But I've never had this issue in the past. If I attempt to repair my razor mediator installation, it removes the value from the `adminUser` attribute, and then Razor doesn't work.

I have restarted Com+, IIS, Tridion Services, and the app pools numerous times.

Comment: Have you restarted the com+?

Comment: I have restarted IIS, the app pool, the Tridion site in IIS, Tridion Services, and Com+

Comment: usually this kind of error gets resolved as @jarnohenneman mentioned. do you have multiple publishers setup?

Comment: nope, just a single publisher.

Comment: Razor doc says: "3.) Once installed, restart the Tridion Content Manager COM+ Package, the Tridion Publisher service, and Template Builder (if it’s open)." if any of these does not work, then box restart can be tried.

Comment: Can you confirm your TRIDION_HOME environment variables are pointing to "C:\apps\sdl\cm\config\Tridion.ContentManager.config"?

Comment: Not that it is an ideal approach, but does the message disappear if you restart the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error typically happens when you don't restart the machine after an installation that requires a restart. If you reboot the machine as requested, the error should go away.

Comment: thank you. I'd restarted everything individually (Com+, Tridion Services, IIS). But when I restarted the machine, it worked fine.